# Derivative of the area of a circle - Unsure why my answer is incorrect

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The initial radius of a circle is $3$cm, but it grows at a rate of $\frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}$

[The problem is taken from this Khan Academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/derivative-applications/rates_of_change/v/rates-of-change-between-radius-and-area-of-circle)

I work out my answer in a similar way to his answer, but he doesn't express the radius as a function of time, and I don't understand why. I've set out my working below as opposed to his working, so you don't have to watch the video if you don't want to.

**MY METHOD**

$A = \pi r^2$  (formula for the area of a circle)

$ r(t) = (3\text{cm} + \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}\Delta_t$) (the radius as a function of time is equal to the initial raidus, of $3$cm, plus the change in radius over time, so at 0 seconds the radius is $3$cm, at time $1$ second the radius is $4$cm and so on)

$\frac {dA}{dt} = \frac {d r(t)}{dt} (\pi (3\text{cm} + \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}\Delta_t)^2)$ (take the derivative)

$\frac {dA}{dt} = 2\pi (3\text{cm} + \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}\Delta_t)\frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}$ (application of the chain rule - derivative of outside function [radius squared] times derivative of inside function [1cm/second*change in time])

$\frac {dA}{dt} = \frac{6\pi \text{cm}^2}{\text{second}} + \frac{2\pi \text{cm}^2 \Delta_t}{\text{second}^2}$ (expand)

**KHAN'S METHOD**

$A = \pi r^2$  (formula for the area of a circle)

$\frac {dA}{dt} = \frac {d r(t)}{dt} (\pi r^2)$

He notes that $r(t) = 3\text{cm}$ and $\frac{d r(t)}{dt} = \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}$ This is where i'm confused. How can radius as a function of time simply be $3$cm? It doesn't account for the fact that it is growing over time. It's literally not a function of time the way he's written it. At least, it doesn't appear to be to me.

$\frac {dA}{dt} = \pi\frac {d r^2(t)}{dt} (r^2)$ (factor out $\pi$)

$\frac {dA}{dt} = 2\pi r \frac{d r(t)}{dt}$ (application of the chain rule)

$\frac {dA}{dt} = 2\pi 3\text{cm} \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}$ (plugging in the values of $r(t)$ and $r'(t)$ above)

$\frac {dA}{dt} =  \frac{6\pi\, \text{cm}^2}{\text{second}}$

So as you can see, I have an extra term whereas the correct answer does not. I can appreciate why they're different, but I don't understand the fault in my reasoning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the derivative at $t=0$. It's not always true that $r(t)=3$, which is a substitution that you made.

Comment: @Winther Yep, I think i've fixed it up now. First time using mathjax so I copy pasted a lot of my formatting

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is my reasoning valid, then? Obviously it's not if we were asked to find the derivative at t = 0, but I don't think we were.

Comment: Welcome to this site btw! It's very good that you took time to learn mathjax. Regarding your question: the video computes $\left.\frac{dA}{dt}\right|_{t=0}$, i.e. the derivative evaluated at $t=0$ just as Thomas said above. You have computed $\frac{dA}{dt}$ in general so to get the Khan answer just take $t = 0$ (or $\Delta_t = 0$ as you call it). You will see that this gives you the same answer.

Comment: Be careful with your notation. The instructor in the video wrote $\frac d{dt}[\pi r^2]$, which is rather different from $\frac {d r(t)}{dt} (\pi r^2)$. Similarly, $\frac {d r(t)}{dt} (\pi (3\text{cm} + \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}\Delta_t)^2)$ in your calculation is not the same thing as $\frac d{dt} (\pi (3\text{cm} + \frac{1\text{cm}}{\text{second}}\Delta_t)^2)$.